# Silverlight Framework - (End User)

Tags: silverlight

I have never used Silverlight before but have been provided a copy of the package, (see link below).

https://github.com/ivconsult/eNeg

Please could I request guidance on how I would compile this and can this be run from desktop or would it need to be uploaded to a server.

Forgive, my poor understanding of how this works any help appreciated . . .

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit rough. You can run any silverlight application locally on your development PC. In order to open and compile the project you have to install:

- A .NET Integrated Development Environment (IDE) such as Visual Studio or the free Visual Web Developer Express
- Install Microsoft Silverlight runtime for windows. (This is the runtime that’s required for Silverlight applications).
- Install Silverlight Toolkit
- Install Silverlight SDK
- Install Silverlight Tools for VS 2010 (Optional)
- Install Expression Blend. This is a design tool that allows users to
  interact with Silverlight.

After this, open the solution file "citPOINT.eNeg.sln".